# What does zsh: suspended ./a.out mean?

Tags: coding-theory, c

I was writing a program to count lines from an input text stream.
This is the program.  It compiles perfectly but when I execute `./a.out` to get the output my program doesn't seem to run.
I enter the text and then enter the command `^z` (control z) and it shows the error mentioned. (`zsh: suspended ./a.out`)

I just want the program to get me the result which it is not showing.

Can you help me, I have just started learning programming.

This is the program just in case you want to check.

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int blank_char, tab_char, new_line;
  blank_char = 0;
  tab_char = 0;
  new_line = 0;
  int c;
  printf("Number of blanks, tabs, and newlines:\n");
  printf("Input few words/tab/newlines\n");
  for (; (c = getchar()) != EOF;)
  {
    if ( c == ' ' ){
      ++blank_char;
    }
    if ( c == '\t' ){
      ++tab_char;
    }
    if ( c == '\n' ){
      ++new_line;
    }
  }  
  printf("blank=%d,tab=%d,newline=%d\n",blank_char,tab_char,new_line);
}
```

Comment: @ Pål GD- thanks, i tried contol d and it is working;but can you tell what this does

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends a job, i.e. it stops it temporarily, and you can restart it by using the commands `fg` or `bg` (resume the job in the foreground or background, respectively, see also `jobs --help`, `fg --help`, `bg --help`).  Technically, it asks the kernel to send the `SIGSTOP` signal to the process.

Similarly, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *kills* the job by sending it the `SIGINT` signal.  This makes it impossible to resume the job.  (See also `man kill`.)

However, your program waits for *end of file* (EOF).
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (the `^D` character) is a special control character that the terminal interprets as *end of file* (or *end of transmission*).  Since your program has a `while` loop that runs until EOF, sending `^D` to the program terminates the `while` loop.

You can read more at [TLDP:Controlling Processes](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x5368.htm),  [TLDP:Other Key combinations](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x1877.htm), [TLDP:Appendix E. Exit Codes With Special Meanings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Comment: thank you so much for broadening my horizon on this topic.@ Pål GD

Comment: No problem, however, in the future, a better place for these types of questions might be
1. [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
2. [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)
3. [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
4. [Software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
(in no particular order).